# Blender objects in outliner, but not visible

Tags: objects, 3d-view

I have a big problem. I have an awesome model, but it isn't visible. All the objects are in the outliner, but I can't see them.

I have tried:

- Period on the number pad
- 3D View Full
- Zooming in and out
- Opening the file in different ways

I am not sure about this whole Clipping Distance thing, though.

Here's the file:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your objects are on layer '1'. When the file opens only layer '5' is set to be visible.

Select the first layer (highlighted in red, below) in the layer selector UI in the *3D View* header to make that layer visible:

[image]

The orange dot in the middle of the sqaure shows that not only is an object on this layer, but that it is currently selected. The fifth square along, which is grey, shows the currently visible layer. There is no dot in the middle of the square, showing that it is empty.

For more information on using layers, see the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/layers.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate the layer in which your object (the orange dot) is:

[image]

All squares represent a view layer. Squares with light grey are hidden layers, while dark grey squares are shown.